# Michigan driver's license

Tags: driving-license, residency, identification

My wife and I are likely to be in an EU country for 10 months starting in the autumn, and my Maryland driver's license is scheduled to expire during that time.

Since all four of our parents live in Michigan, and since we probably plan to move to that region after coming back, is there a way for me to get a Michigan driver's license? Or do I need to get a Maryland license for now, then convert after we move back?

Comment: If you will be abandoning your Maryland residence when you go to Europe then you may want to "move in" with your parents or in-laws just before, to establish your domicile in Michigan. Transfer your driver's license and maybe register to vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually states require a proof of residency in the state in order to convert out of state driver's license (along with possible other requirements)

[Michigan requires 2 pieces](http://www.michigan.gov/documents/sos/Applying_for_lic_or_ID_SOS_428_222146_7.pdf) submitted to the Secretary of State office which usually require a utility bill or something similar to prove that you actually live in the state.

So for simplicity I would renew my Maryland Driver's License and then when you move back to the states obtain your Michigan one.